# Review of java interface for constructing brain model

Tags: java, object-oriented, unit-testing, junit

I have built a partial human brain model and the following is an example of how I use all the classes. I was wondering if anyone could critique my implementation strategies because I feel like the following setup is very clumsy. You can view all the code at:
https://github.com/quinnliu/WalnutiQ

```
public class HowToUseMARK_I extends junit.framework.TestCase {
    private NervousSystem nervousSystem;
    private MemoryClassifier memoryClassifier_Digits;

    private Gson gson;

    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        this.gson = new Gson();
        this.nervousSystem = this.constructConnectedNervousSystem();
        this.memoryClassifier_Digits = this.trainMemoryClassifierWithNervousSystem();
    }

    private NervousSystem constructConnectedNervousSystem() {
        // construct Neocortex with just V1
        Region rootRegionOfNeocortex = new Region("V1", 4, 4, 4, 50, 3);
        RegionToRegionConnect neocortexConnectType = new RegionToRegionRectangleConnect();
        Neocortex unconnectedNeocortex = new Neocortex(rootRegionOfNeocortex,
                neocortexConnectType);

        // construct LGN
        Region LGNRegion = new Region("LGN", 8, 8, 1, 50, 3);
        LateralGeniculateNucleus unconnectedLGN = new LateralGeniculateNucleus(
                LGNRegion);

        // construct Retina
        VisionCell[][] visionCells = new VisionCell[65][65];
        for (int x = 0; x < visionCells.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < visionCells[0].length; y++) {
                visionCells[x][y] = new VisionCell();
            }
        }
        Retina unconnectedRetina = new Retina(visionCells);

        // construct 1 object of NervousSystem to encapsulate all classes in
        // MARK II
        NervousSystem nervousSystem = new NervousSystem(unconnectedNeocortex,
                unconnectedLGN, unconnectedRetina);

        // connect Retina to LGN
        Retina retina = nervousSystem.getPNS().getSNS().getRetina();

        LateralGeniculateNucleus LGN = nervousSystem.getCNS().getBrain()
                .getThalamus().getLGN();

        SensorCellsToRegionConnect retinaToLGN = new SensorCellsToRegionRectangleConnect();
        retinaToLGN.connect(retina.getVisionCells(), LGN.getRegion(), 0, 0);

        // connect LGN to V1 Region of Neocortex
        Neocortex neocortex = nervousSystem.getCNS().getBrain().getCerebrum()
                .getCerebralCortex().getNeocortex();

        RegionToRegionConnect LGNToV1 = new RegionToRegionRectangleConnect();
        LGNToV1.connect(LGN.getRegion(), neocortex.getCurrentRegion(), 0, 0);

        return nervousSystem;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would consider making this code:

   ```
   // construct Retina
   VisionCell[][] visionCells = new VisionCell[65][65];
   for (int x = 0; x < visionCells.length; x++) {
       for (int y = 0; y < visionCells[0].length; y++) {
           visionCells[x][y] = new VisionCell();
       }
   }
   ```

   a factory method on `Retina` (passing in the dimensions of the cell array) as it will probably be a common thing to create.
2. Call chains like these `nervousSystem.getPNS().getSNS().getRetina()` are a code smell. You could model your nervous system as some kind of repository where you can query the individual components like this:

   ```
   nervousSystem.getRetina();
   nervousSystem.getBrain();
   ```

   or fully generic (additional bonus points ;))

   ```
   nervousSystem.get<Retina>();
   nervousSystem.get<Brain>();
   ```

   More complex components like `Brain` can then be modeled in the same way:

   ```
   nervousSystem.get<Brain>().get<Neocortex>();
   ```

   This alleviates the caller from having to know the internal structure.
3. I find it quite weird that your ctor for the `NervousSystem` only takes some very specific components of individual subsystems. From the looks of it the `NervousSystem` is composed out of `PNS` and `CNS` with `SNS` being part of  the `PNS` and `Brain` being part of the `CNS` etc. so I'm wondering why the `NervousSystem` is not being built like that but gets some very specific subcomponents instead.

   I would have thought the setup should look something like this (I haven't checked the code on github so the class names are purely guesswork):

   ```
   Neocortex neocortex = new Neocortex(...);
   CerebralCortex cerebralCortex = new CerebralCortex(neocortex, ...);
   Cerebrum cerebrum = new Cerebrum(cerebralCortex, ...);

   LateralGeniculateNucleus lgn = new LateralGeniculateNucleus(...);
   Thalamus thalamus = new Thalamus(lgn, ...);

   Brain brain = new Brain(cerebrum, thalamus, ...);
   CNS cns = new CNS(brain, ...);

   Retina retina = new Retina(...);
   SNS sns = new SNS(retina, ...);
   PNS pns = new PNS(sns, ...);

   NervousSystem nervousSystem = new NervousSystem(cns, pns);
   ```
4. For wiring individual components up you could pass a `WiringStrategy` into the `NervousSystem` which decides how things are wired up (so you can simulate broken wiring for example).

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you very much. To answer your 3rd question I have only implemented very small parts of the brain and if I created the setup you suggested I would just have a lot of filler classes right now. But your suggested setup is the goal ;)

Comment: I like your idea in #2. Can you explain how I can make the getter method fully generic? Like do I need a class that everything in a Nervous System extends?

Answer (score 1):

Well, nobody said that modelling the brain would be easy.

However, it you find that it takes a lot of code to set up the nervous system model, it's probably a sign that your library is underdeveloped.  Maybe the library should include some kind of `NervousSystemFactory` for convenience.  Maybe the library should support a configuration file to describe the connections.  YAML, for example, lets you [reference other nodes within a document](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2786196), which might be a useful feature for this application.